# how to capture column values from a lightning:datatable to compare two of its column values

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I am working on a datatable :

That Displays;
Description , Due Date, Reminder Date
History     November 26, 19    November 25, 19

How to compare Due date with Reminder Date to display an alert message

Comment: welcome to SFSE, Please update your question with what you have tried so far & where you struck add your code snippet or at least explain what u need with pictures. so that it'll easy to give best solution for u

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in JavaScript, and render that on the dataTable. You will have to build the Data and then use that Data List to populate the DataTable Column.